# Why does box-sizing: padding-box look different on a mac?

Tags: html, css, macos

```css
#map-search-button {
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: url(https://i.imgur.com/r35pKjB.png) 8 8 8 8;
    border-width: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    height: 50px;
    width: 125px;
    background-color: #00ACC8;
    background-clip: padding-box !important;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-search-button">Find us!</div>
```

On Chrome on Windows, the button looks the way I expected:

[image]

But on Chrome on a Mac, the button looks like this:

[image]

Why is this?  Is there anything in the CSS I can change that would keep the border image solid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’d highly recommend creating a rounded button with [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) rather than trying to implement a [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image). See inline example below.

As for a technical explanation of why yours doesn’t look right, you may want to look into best practices for producing a border-image if you want to further pursue that route. Your Mac may have a Retina display and be improperly scaling your image.

**Using `border-radius`:**

```css
body {
  font-family: impact, sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: .02em;
}

#map-search-button {
  width: 125px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: #00ACC8;
  border: 5px solid #00ACC8;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-search-button">FIND US!</div>
```